# Would java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray() return null?

Tags: java, null, bytearrayoutputstream

Just like the title shows, I couldn't find any clue about it in Javadoc.

Comment: I am so looking forward to `@Nullable`, `@NotNullable` annotations in the JDK...

Comment: Both the JavaDoc and the source in Sun's JDK is clear - it won't ever happen.

Comment: *"I couldn't find any clue about it in Javadoc"* The clue is that the Javadoc **doesn't** say that it will return `null`. Therefore, it won't.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Well, that is not something I would rely on.

Comment: @Thilo: If a method returns `null` without documenting it as a return value, it's a bug (in the method, or the Javadoc). If you catch anyone (including Sun/Oracle) doing it, report said bug to them. :-)

Answer (score 4):

No, it never will. It would never make *sense* to return null, and if you look at the implementation it definitely won't. (I realize it's generally better to rely on the documented guarantees than the implementation, but I see no reason to suppose it would ever return null here.)

In particular, the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) states:

> Creates a newly allocated byte array.

and

> Returns: the current contents of this output stream, as a byte array.

Those wouldn't be correct if it returned null, would it?

Answer (score 0):

It would return `null` in one way ;)

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
{
    public byte[] toByteArray()
    {
        return null;
    }
};
System.out.println(baos.toByteArray());
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
null
```

Comment: Yes, but at that point it's not obeying the contract in the Javadoc, is it?

Comment: @JonSkeet You are right, but it at least it can return `null` at the end :)

Comment: That isn't a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. It's a `ByteArrayOutputStream` interface to a *derived* class (and one that's violating its parent's contract, as Jon pointed out).

Comment: But it's not a java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray() actually ;)

Answer (score 0):

No it wouldn't. Ever. Look into the code ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray:

```
public synchronized byte toByteArray()[] {
    return Arrays.copyOf(buf, count);
}
```

Arrays.copyOf:

```
public static byte[] copyOf(byte[] original, int newLength) {
    byte[] copy = new byte[newLength];
    System.arraycopy(original, 0, copy, 0,
                     Math.min(original.length, newLength));
    return copy;
}
```